# Solving SDE $dx_t = (a) x_t dt + (b) dZ_t$

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

I am new to stochastic differential equations. I would like to solve something like this:

$dx_t = (a) x_t dt + (b) dZ_t$

The solution is:

$x_t = e^{at} x_0 + b e^{at} \int_0^t e^{-au} dZ_u$

I would like to understand the steps to find the solution. All examples I have managed to find are of the type:

$dx_t = (a) x_t dt + (b) x_t dZ_t$

Could someone help me understand the steps or direct me towards a useful resource?

Comment: You have a sign error somewhere in front of $a$. // The solution is here via integrating factor, consider $y_t=e^{at}x_t$ and apply the Ito formula (which is trivial, does not have extra terms over the product formula, as $y$ is linear in $x$).

Comment: Thank you. I will solve it and add the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the SDE, consider $W_t = e^{- a t} x_t$. By Ito's lemma:
\begin{align}
dW_t &= - a e^{- a t} x_t dt + e^{- a t} dx_t \\
dW_t &= - a e^{- a t} x_t dt + e^{- a t} (a x_t dt + b dZ_t) \nonumber \\
dW_t &= (- a e^{- a t} x_t + a e^{- a t} x_t) dt + b e^{- a t} dZ_t \nonumber \\
dW_t &= b e^{- a t} dZ_t \nonumber
\end{align}
Integrating both sides:
\begin{align}
\int_0^t d(e^{- a u} x_u) &= b \int_0^t e^{- a u} dZ_u \\
e^{- a t} x_t &= x_0 + b \int_0^t e^{- a u} dZ_u \nonumber \\
x_t &= e^{a t} x_0 + e^{a t} b \int_0^t e^{- a u} dZ_u \nonumber
\end{align}